# else part is not working when using arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to know why my else condition is not working. `If` part is working but the `else` part is not. I want to compare a string in a array list and print its status whether it is found in the list or not.

```
for(int i=0;i<laptop.size();i++)
{
     if(serialno.equals(laptop.get(i).getSerialno()))
     {
         laptop.remove(i);
         System.out.println("Deleted");
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println("Laptop not found in the list");
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how the else condition is failing? Does it never print "Laptop not found in the list"? Does it print it too often? Or is something else wrong?

Comment: With your current implementation, you're removing items from the collection that you're iterating over, so laptop.size will change every time that you remove one, and you will skip items in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to break from the loop if deleted and also only print the status after all looping is done

```
boolean isDeleted = false;
for(int i=0;i<laptop.size();i++)
{
     if(serialno.equals(laptop.get(i).getSerialno()))
     {
         laptop.remove(i);
         isDeleted = true;
         break;
     }
}

if(isDeleted)
{
     System.out.println("Deleted");
}
else
{
     System.out.println("Laptop not found in the list");
 }
```

Comment: You don't break from the list once deleted here, and you're calling remove on the list that you're iterating on (so laptop.size() will change as you delete ones from the inner loop)

Comment: @Mike That was dumd of me to say `break` and not actually do it.  Thanks for the heads up.